# How to use a different database with Windows Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I searched a lot for database compatibility with Windows Azure for databases other than SQL Azure, but could not find.
I just want to know whether SQL Azure is the only database which can be used with Azure or are there ways to integrate others also.
Is it possible to do it using a custom VM role? If yes, then how to do that..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You can run anything you like on an Azure Worker role, as long as you can configure it in a load-balanceable way (e.g. with replication/mirroring). This is because you need at least two instances of the role to get the SLA, and the Azure App Fabric controller *will* reboot your servers from time to time to perform patches and upgrades.

You also have to use CloudDrive for storage; this is a VHD file which is held as a paged blob in the Blob Storage service, so it persists when a role is recycled.

I built an example of running RavenDB on Azure which is on my GitHub here: https://github.com/markrendle/AzureRavenDB

10gen have a "MongoDB Azure wrapper" available, details here: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MongoDB+on+Azure

The same principles used in these packages can be applied to MySQL and other relational databases.

Answer (score 0):

At the time being, it's not possible with the VM role because your VM role will be recycled and your data would be lost when this happens.

There are rumors that a persistent VM role will be provided in the future, which would allow you to install any database on a persistent VM role and use that database for your applications. But a persistent VM role is not available at this moment.

If you really are in need of a relational database and you can not use SQL Azure, you could keep your database on-premises and use the **Windows Azure connect service** to connect your windows azure applications to your on-premises database. However this will have a higher latency than using a data provider like SQL Azure or table/blob storage.

How to do this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh509003.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Well on Azure you have, out of the box, SQL azure db and table storage().

You can run number of other db's in your custom setup... what do you want to run, at least what type of db ?

VM role is really good for all custom things. You can install there anything you could on normal windows. Yes it is not persistent but that can be overcome with custom windows service. take a look here:
http://techyfreak.blogspot.com/2011/02/mounting-azure-drive-in-azure-virtual.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: While VM Role is valuable when an installation is manual-only or takes too long, VM Role should not be the go-to recommendation, as you can run nearly anything you want in a Web or Worker role, via startup tasks, without the extra task of creating and managing an OS image.

Comment: @David: you are right. for instance I run MongoDB in worker roles...however question is very generic...and VM role sound as the most generic answer :) (with all its downsides)